# SQL DB User's changes

Tags: sql-server

I , unknowingly, create a user in database with loginname of 'windows_user' instead of sql server user , now enable to drop.
pl suggest the way ..

Comment: what do you mean "enable to drop?" give him rights to change the database schema?

Answer (score 1):

try using: [DROP USER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189438.aspx)